# Autogenerated codes of Database in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I created a database in Visual Studio 2010 from Server Explorer. I want to see the auto generated codes created by Visual Studio. Where to find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no auto generated code. It creates a database on the server you specified in the Create New SQL Server Database dialog box.

Comment: possibly, sorry but i am new to this field. dont know what you are asking....perhaps what i am asking